# Hiding label on a specific range value

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a practical way to hide a label of an input type range when its value is lower than a specific number.
And then showing it again when the value goes back to a specific minimum number.

any idea?

Thanks

```js
$('input[type="range"]').on('mouseup', function() {
  this.blur();
}).on('mousedown input', function() {
  $('#1').text(this.value + "%");
  $('#2').text(100 - this.value + "%");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" />

  <div class="container2">
    <label id="1">50%</label>
  </div>

  <div class="container3">
    <label id="2">50%</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `if` statement to validate your condition and than use `hide()` or `show()` on the element you want to display or not.

In the example below, label with `id="2"` is shown when value is greater or equal to 50 and hidden when value is lower.

```js
$('input[type="range"]').on('mouseup', function() {
  this.blur();
}).on('mousedown input', function() {
  var label1value = this.value;
  var label2value = 100 - this.value;

  $('#1').text(this.value + "%");
  $('#2').text(100 - this.value + "%");
  
  // compare value greater or equal to 50
  if (this.value >= 50) {
    // show element when condition is true
    $('#2').show();
  } else {
    // hide element when condition is false
    $('#2').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="50" />

  <div class="container2">
    <label id="1">50%</label>
  </div>

  <div class="container3">
    <label id="2">50%</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. As I will have to place several slides in the same page, I'm looking for a way to target a specific slide with a specific js. Right now the js targets all the input[type="range"] on the page. How can I target only that div. or class or id?https://codepen.io/Waterbear83/pen/MWwGPxJ

Comment: You just need to be more specific on the selector `$('input[type="range"]')`. In your codepen example you could change it to `$('.container5 > input[type="range"]')` to only target the input of type `range` that is inside the element with class `container5`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not really sure of what you really want to achieve but here is a code sample and a demo.
The range label disappears when value is lower than 50.

**Using Vanilla JS**

```
// On document ready
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // set a range limit to show/hide range label
  var rangeLimit = 50;

  // When range value changes, call this listener
  function rangeValueListener(event) {
    var rangeElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
    setRangeLabelValue(rangeElement);
  }

  // Update range label for a range element
  function setRangeLabelValue(rangeElement) {
    var rangeLabelElement = document.querySelector(
      'label[for="' + rangeElement.id + '"]'
    );
    // Update label text using range value
    var rangeValue = rangeElement.value;
    rangeLabelElement.innerText = rangeValue + "%";
    // if range value is lower than limit, hide it else restore initial state
    if (rangeValue < rangeLimit) {
      rangeLabelElement.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      rangeLabelElement.style.display = "initial";
    }
  }

  // Get range element
  var rangeElement = document.querySelector("#myRange");
  // Attach a listener to change range label when range value change
  rangeElement.addEventListener("input", rangeValueListener);
  rangeElement.addEventListener("change", rangeValueListener);
  // Set initial range label
  setRangeLabelValue(rangeElement);
});
```

**Code snippet using jQuery** (without explanation, code is simply adapted)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rangeLimit = 50;
  var rangeDefaultValue = 65;

  function rangeValueListener(event) {
    setRangeLabelValue(event.target);
  }

  function setRangeLabelValue(rangeElement) {
    var rangeElementId = rangeElement.id || rangeElement.attr("id");
    var rangeLabelElement = $('label[for="' + rangeElementId + '"]');
    var rangeValue = rangeElement.value || rangeDefaultValue;
    rangeLabelElement.text(rangeValue + "%");
    if (rangeValue < rangeLimit) {
      rangeLabelElement.hide();
    } else {
      rangeLabelElement.show();
    }
  }

  var rangeElement = $("#myRange");
  rangeElement.on("input change", rangeValueListener);
  setRangeLabelValue(rangeElement);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="myRange" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="65" />
    <label for="myRange"></label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually used an if condition, and it works fine, thanks. As I will have to place several slides in the same page, I'm looking for a way to target a specific slide with a specific js. Right now the js targets all the input[type="range"] on the page. How can I target only that slide?codepen.io/Waterbear83/pen/MWwGPxJ